# How to count the combinations of unique values per group in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table with sessions and want to count the session that the userID goes through.

1 session and 1 count of sessions.

| date | userID | session |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | facebook |
| 2022-01-02 | 1 | google |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 | facebook |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 | google |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | facebook |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | google |
| 2022-01-03 | 2 | tiktok |
| 2022-01-03 | 3 | tiktok |

output is

| session | count |
| --- | --- |
| tiktok | 1 |
| facebook google | 1 |
| facebook google tiktok | 1 |

So the count is based on a unique user with the session that the user id has been exposed to.

Comment: Is the output your expect? Session `tiktok` should has count with 2 cause `userID` [2,3].

Comment: hi yes, the output is what is expected. tiktok still counts as 1, as user id 2, has to go through facebook, google before tiktok. So it sees the user journey.  for single session is easy because we can check len of user_id == 1

Comment: the logic is quite unclear, why 2 times "facebook google"? Can you explicit all the counts by breaking down the calculations?

Comment: hi sorry, have edited the mistake, facebook google  should only appear 1 time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to find the unique combinations of sites, without duplicates (but it remains unclear whether order is important).

###### In order (A->B is different than B->A):

```
(df.groupby('userID')['session']
   .agg(lambda x: tuple(dict.fromkeys(x)))
   .value_counts()
)
```

output:

```
(facebook, google)            1
(facebook, google, tiktok)    1
(tiktok,)                     1
Name: session, dtype: int64
```

or, to illustrate the order:

```
(df.groupby('userID')['session']
   .agg(lambda x: '->'.join(dict.fromkeys(x)))
   .value_counts()
)
```

output:

```
facebook->google            1
facebook->google->tiktok    1
tiktok                      1
Name: session, dtype: int64
```

###### Order independent (A->B would count as B->A):

```
(df.groupby('userID')['session']
   .agg(frozenset)
   .value_counts()
)
```

output:

```
(facebook, google)            1
(facebook, tiktok, google)    1
(tiktok)                      1
Name: session, dtype: int64
```